# Hide POSTGRESQL partitioned tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, pg-partman

I'm using pg_partman to partition three of my tables and and ended up with a large number of child tables.

Some users find it difficult to navigate whit their database tool (DBeaver or SQuirreL) with this increasing number of tables showing up.

Is there a way to "hide" these table from a user without changing their access rights to them ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the partitions, but you could put them in a different schema than the partitioned table. Then they are “hidden” if you only look at the schema with the partitioned table.

Comment: Yes I already thought of that but by doing so I'm unable to use partman's functions and procedures

Answer (score 0):

bump into same question, and didn't found a perfect solution. My work around here is to filter out tables with name %*prt*%